# Are home theatre questions on topic here?

Tags: discussion

If I had a question about HDCP, HDMI over ethernet, and using an HD projector as a second display for an iMac be considered on topic here?

Answer (score 5):

Highly, highly unlikely.  Sounds like maybe a question for super user.  This really has nothing to do with video production as far as I can tell.